# Number of positive integer solutions.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider $$ {xy \over x+y} = 2^4 \times 3^5  \times 5^4 $$

Find the number of positive integer solutions to this equation.

Comment: Had you found anyone?@RitikGarg

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+xy%2F(x%2By)%3D2%5E4*3%5E5*5%5E4+integers) tells us that the only solution is $x = 2430001$, $y = 5904902430000$

Comment: $ x=y= 2^5 × 3^5 × 5^4$?

Comment: But it's about finding the number of solutions rather than the solutions themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $xy=n(x+y)$
then
$(x-n)(y-n) =n^2$.

For each factorization
$n^2=ab$
there is a solution
$x=a+n, y=b+n$
so the answer is
the number of factorizations
of $n^2$.